# Angular TS Lint onInit vs ngOnInit

Tags: angular, tslint

I received a warning from TS Lint that I need to implement OnInit interface and provided me with a link to this page : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#09-01

What is the difference between `onInit` and `ngOnInit`. Both worked for me .
Why is ok to use `ngOnInit` and not `onInit` which is much simple to write?

Comment: `OnInit` is the interface, implementing it requires you to define the method `ngOnInit`. This is explained in the docs you've linked to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular always checks for lifecycle hooks, whether your class implements the interface or not.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

So if you have this class:

```
export class MyComponent {
    ngOnInit() { ... }
}
```

It will work fine (ngOnInit will be called by the framework).  However, it is a good idea to implement the interface to ensure the method has been properly implemented.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() { ... }
}
```

Note that `onInit` is NOT a lifecycle hook and will not be called by Angular -- it is simply the name of the interface saying that you `implement` `ngOnInit` method somewhere in your class.

Comment: *"it's good to signal to other developers"* - that's not really what it's for, though; per the documentation the OP links it's so the compiler can warn you about e.g. writing `ngOnInt` and spending a day wondering why it never gets called.

Comment: I mean, that's fine with me too.  Simply another benefit of implementing the interface.